# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock returns nil upon successful query

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, parse-platform

My current problem is that my -findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method is return nil for a successful query.

My custom class is a JSON which was imported using the {results: [{}]} syntax. There are 22 dictionaries in my JSON - {results: [ 22 dictionaries ]}. My custom class is correctly declared and spelled in the "let query..." declaration. When I run my code the "print(query)" line outputs "PFQuery: 0x7faadb527f40" so I assume that the query is successful? By successful I mean that the query identifies that there is a class call "BarLibrary" on my parse site - which there is.

With this code below if I change [PFObject]? to [AnyObject]? I get a segmentation 11 error. With [PFObject]? as the type of "objects" in -findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock I always get a nil.

My goal is to successfully pull my JSON data from parse.com and store it into "objects".

[My Class Name and # of items in JSON as seen on my parse account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUsTL.png)

The data in my custom JSON is structured like the following:

```
{ 
"results" :  [{
        "name": String,
        "address": String,
        "image": String,
        "latitude" : double,
        "longitude" : double,

        "Monday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        },
        "Tuesday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        },
        "Wednesday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        },
        "Thursday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        },
        "Friday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        },
        "Saturday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        },
        "Sunday" : {   "key1": String,
            "key2":String,
            "key3": 16,
            "key4": 19,
            "key5": 999,
            "key6": 999,
            "key7": String,
            "key8": String
        }
          ...... // 22 total dictionaries like this in the array "results"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import Foundation
import Parse


struct getBarJSON {

init(){

    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "BarLibrary")
    print("\n")
    print("Result of the query")
    print("=========================")
    print(query) // <PFQuery: Hex Number>

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError? )-> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // Do something upon successfull network request
            print("\n")
            print("Result of Network Request")
            print("=========================")

            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                    print(objects)
                }

        } else {
            // Report the error
            print("\n")
            print("Error Description:")
            print("==================")
            print(error)
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Try changing the line to read: "if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {"

Comment: @picciano, thanks for answering . And If I do that I get an error that reads "Downcast from [PFObject]? to [PFObject] only unwraps optionals, did you mean to use !"  - manipulation that line thus far only prompts more errors and warnings.

Comment: Have you read through https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries ? Their documentation is better than their support...

Comment: The print query tells you that you have created a query object and nothing more. No communication with the parse backend has taken place at that point. It would seem that your object class name is wrong or that there is no data in parse. Can you see it in the web browser?

Comment: @picciano yes I have read through the IOS guide and I will continue to read it over and over.

Comment: @Paulw11 I included a picture in the link in the picture above. I have successfully imported my data and spelled my custom class name correctly.

Comment: As mentioned by @Paulw11, printing out the query is irrelevant and doesn't give you any meaningful information in this case. The cast you're performing in the completion block doesn't seem to be doing anything either. Try calling `print(objects)` immediately after `print("Result of Network Request")` rather than inside of `if let objects = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thank you all for the responses. I finally got my code to work correctly.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import Parse


struct getBarJSON {

var barLibrary : [PFObject]?

init(){
    // Pull data from parse

    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "BarLibrary")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError? )-> Void in

        print("\n")
        print("Result of Network Request")
        print("=========================")

        if error == nil {
            // Do something upon successfull network request
            print("\n")
            print("Result of the query")
            print("=========================")
            if var objects = objects { // unrwapping the optional
                for object in objects { // iterating over the array of PFObjects
                    objects.append(object)
                }
            }
            print("\(objects!.count) dictionaries retrieved ")
            self.barLibrary = objects
        } else {
            // Report the error
            print("\n")
            print("Error Description:")
            print("==================")
            print(error)
        }
     // end of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock closure
    }

 // end of getBarJSON init()
}

// end of getBarJSON struct declaration
}
```

I get a total of 22 [PFObjects]? stored in 'barLibrary' which is exactly what I was looking for. @driver733 's response helped guide me in the right direction as what I was to do exactly.

Now my next challenge is to figure out how to use PFObject Sub-classing to parse my data!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to get objects from a query. If you still get nil, then you should check the data that your "BarLibrary" class table has (and maybe post sample contents here, in order to understand its structure) The current login prints out PFObjects irrespectively of their properties.

```
import Foundation
import Parse


struct getBarJSON {

init(){

    let query = PFQuery(className: "BarLibrary")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError? )-> Void in
        print("\n")
        print("Result of Network Request")
        print("=========================")
        if error == nil {
            print("\n")
            print("Result of the query")
            print("=========================")

            if let objects = objects {   // unwrapping an optional
                for object in objects {  // iterating over the array of pfobjects
                    print(object)
                    if let customObject = object["someProperty"] as? String { // in case you store a string. The process in similar for numbers, arrays, etc.
                      print(customObject.characters.count)
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            // Report the error
            print("\n")
            print("Error Description:")
            print("==================")
            print(error)
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: I included the details of my JSON in my problem description. I used your code and 'objects' still returns nil. When I try to use the optional downcast in 'if let customObject = object as? String' The editor issues a warning that says "Cast from PFObject to unrelated type always fails". Any type I put after 'as?' gives me this warning. @driver733

Comment: My bad. You have case your PFObject property to the other type, not the PFObject itself.
Thank you for posting the JSON. I will report to you after I import it into my parse database and see whether I can get the objects or not.

Comment: I used the code I posted without any changes. After I successfully imported the JSON you provided
http://pastebin.com/11FQKPuv  http://i73.fastpic.ru/big/2015/1026/fb/de562e9117bf4e1d1d54220b9cc39afb.png
I was able to get the data.
http://pastebin.com/xsZYM7W5
Please try importing the data again and see if it works.